# Как вывести данные полностью из 6 таблиц бд MariaDB

Tags: mysql, select

Имею 6 таблиц с одинаковыми колонками id services price unit. Идея заключается в том что бы по клику на сайте подгрузить эти 6 таблиц. Наполнение таблиц разное. В будущем возможно пополнение.

Пробовал
 `$PDO->query("SELECT * FROM cable_laying, black_work")`. В 1й таблице 12 записей во 2й 8, так мне приходит 96 записей, 2й таблицы каждая строка повторяется по 8 раз.
SELECT такое ощущение рассматривает только одну таблицу `SELECT cable_laying.*, black_work.*` тоже не помогает.
INNER JOIN это всё выборка. Ощущение что нужно делать 6 отдельных запросов ибо мыслей больше нет.

UPD:
Не знаю на сколько грамотно, но строка запроса получилась длинной

```
$tables = ["black_work", "clean_work", "cable_laying", "low_volt_system", "retro_wiring", "pipe_install"];
$queryStr = "";

foreach ($tables as $item) {
    
    if($item == $tables[count($tables) - 1]){
        $queryStr .= "SELECT * FROM $item";
        break;
    }
    $queryStr .= "SELECT * FROM $item UNION ";
}
```

Comment: Union all вам в помощь

Comment: Нормализуйте данные - сделайте одну таблицу, добавьте поле номера исходной таблицы, и соберите в неё все данные из всех 6 таблиц. Проблема сама собой рассосётся.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте Union All

```
SELECT cable_laying.*
From cable_laying
Union All
SELECT black_work.*
From black_work
```

Конечно будет работать только если колонки одинаковые. Если нет то приведите к одинаковым.